# How to use file path from a cell in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, path, cell

I'm running a VBA script in order to count number of rows in each file in a selected folder and then to display it in an active Workbook.

```
 Option Explicit
Sub CountRows()
    Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbDest As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String
    Dim lngNextRow As Long, lngRowCount As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wbDest = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsDest = wbDest.ActiveSheet

    strFolder = Dir(Range("C7").Value)
    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.xlsx")
    lngNextRow = 11
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFolder & strFile)
        Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(1)
        lngRowCount = wsSource.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        wsDest.Cells(lngNextRow, "F").Value = lngRowCount
        wbSource.Close savechanges:=False
        lngNextRow = lngNextRow + 1
        strFile = Dir
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Chooing a folder, I would like to use the directory that is inserted in an active WorkBook cell "C7" instead of writing a directory in a script.
I tried to substitute:

```
strFolder = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\"
```

with

```
 strFolder = Dir(Range("C7").Value)
```

but it does not work. Maybe someone has any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: try to add fully qualified name to your `Range` as follows: `Workbooks("wbName").Worksheets("shName").Range("C7")`

Comment: I don't know if anything different was expectet to happen: however for me id did work "as is": I put this into C7:   C:\Users\tstracke\Desktop\U-Wert-Rechner\test
In your document I got the number 21 inserted in cell F11. 21 is the number of rows in one document in the specified folder.

Comment: Sorry, i did not get it. I mean how exactly should i define strFolder ?

Comment: @Thomas Stracke  yes, was expected that starting from the cell F11 we can see the number of rows in the files of a selected folder (if file is just 1, so will be just 1 number in F11). But if i put the folder path in C7 and define strFolder = Dir(Range("C7").Value) to me it does not work.

Comment: @Ale, try to add `MsgBox Range("C7").Value` just before line `strFolder = Dir(Range("C7").Value)`. What message would appear?

Comment: Could you try to give a description what exacly happens? Id did work for me without changing your above code. Maybe a cell format issue?

Comment: @simoco appears a message with directory that i've inserted in C7

Comment: can you show me content of your `C7`?

Comment: @simoco sure, in C7 i have:
C:\Users\aleksandra.sergejeva\Desktop\VBA\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `strFolder = Dir(Range("C7").Value)` finds firts file in directory (from `C7`) and then writes *path of this file* into variable `strFolder` (say, `C:\temp\somefile.txt`).

Next line of your code: `strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.xlsx")` takes this path and adds `*.xlsx`. In result you would get `strFile = Dir("C:\temp\somefile.txt*.xlsx")` and that's wrong.

So, change this code:

```
strFolder = Dir(Range("C7").Value)
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.xlsx")
```

to next one:

```
strFolder = Range("C7").Value
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.xlsx")
```

Btw, I'd recommend you to specify sheet for `Range("C7")` like this: `wsDest.Range("C7")`

Comment: Thank you! With 'strFolder = Range("C7").Value' it works fine! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
dim strPath as string
strPath = CurDir + "NameofFile.xls"
```