# File Path Changed Dependent On Cell Value (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

i think this will be really basic and i have tried to refer to multiple threads ([How to use file path from a cell in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877684/how-to-use-file-path-from-a-cell-in-vba)). But cant seem to get any code working without any issues.

Basically what i want to do is open different XL files dependent on an input from a cell, all the files are in the same location (folder), but obviously the name will alter. So in cell C3 i write a number e.g. 12345 and i want it to look in a constant folder for the corresponding named XL document.

All files are saved in C:\ ***** \ *****\Documents\My Work, i want to open the folder C:\ ***** \ *****\Documents\My Work\12345.XLS which changes dependent on C3.

Here is the code i attempted to use:

```
Sub Macro()
Dim Filelocation As String
Dim File As String
Dim Filepathfull As String
Filelocation = "C:\ ***** \ *****\Documents\My Work"
File = "C3"
Filepathfull="Filelocation & "\" & "File" & ".xlsx"
Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Filepathfull)
End Sub
```

Ill keep looking in the meantime! thanks for your help in advance.

EDIT WITH ANSWER:

```
Sub Macro()
Dim Filelocation As String
Dim File As String
Dim Filepathfull As String
Filelocation = "C:\ ***** \ *****\Documents\My Work"
File = "C3"
Filepathfull = Filelocation & "\" & Range(File).Value & ".xlsx"
Workbooks.Open (Filepathfull)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (**Untested**)

```
Filepathfull= Filelocation & "\" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range(File).Value & ".xls"
```

`Filelocation` and `File` are variables. Treat them as such. Anything that you put in quotes will be considered as a string.

In the above code change `Sheet1` to the relevant sheet. i.e the sheet where the file names are.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Comment: Just an add on from your code, how would i reference the range as a workbook aswell as the sheet. because i need to add this so my whole code will work

Comment: I am sorry. I do not understand your quesiton

Comment: As in you have the code, 'Sheets("Sheet1").Range(File).Value' is there anyway i can amend this code to also define the workbook aswell as the sheet

Comment: Yup. `Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(File).Value` or replace `Thisworkbook` with the actual workbook object

Comment: So say for example if i have a XL file named Hello.xlsx could i write, `Hello.xlsx.Sheets("sheet1").Range(File).Value`??

Comment: If the workbook is open then you can use this `Workbooks("Hello.xlsx").Sheets("sheet1).Range(File).Value`

Comment: And you, my dear friend, are very kind :)